# SysTray Icon not visible after restart for a program running as administrator

Tags: c#, windows-vista, system-tray, administrator, runas

I have a simplest form of an application, in which I am showing a SysTray Icon and adding the application in Startup items. Application is developed in C#. I want tray icon to be shown even after restart of the machine. Currently, I am facing a strange behavior while running the exe using "Run as Administrator". When I use under administrator rights , icon doesn't come after machine restart (though exe is still running). I am using following Metadata values in metadata "requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"":

I had to use "invoker" (not "administrator") because it was not adding it as startup items without it. It is working fine if I run exe using double click( as now it runs under current user domain instead of administrator) but this exe would start by installer thus started in System domain. Can any one help me to sort out this issue?

Either provide me solution so that it can show Systray icon while running as administrator or better if you can provide me any way so that I can start this Exe under current user domain instead of admin?

Regards
Sumeet Garg

Comment: How are you currently starting the exe upon restart?

Comment: I am added exe path as a string value in following registry path: 

SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am calling exe now from another component (A Shell extension), which always run in user Domain. Hence the called exe working User domain by default. Thanks for all the support.